# Doctrine: strange behavior in update with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="A")
 */ 
class A {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="a")
     */
    protected $bs;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="B")
 */ 
class B {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     /**
     protected $id;

    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="bs")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_a", referencedColumnName="id")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
    */
    protected $a;

}
```

On my db, table B has key (id, id_a).
On edit method, i get B by id_b and id_a and I perform flush on EntityManager:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $b = $em->getRepository('B')->find(array('id' => $id_b,'a' => $id_a));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($b)
        ->add(...)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
        ...
```

changes are applied on all B rows with id_b and id_a are not considered.

Any help would appreciated,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get an error with your repository method. You're using the method *find* or the signature of the methode is :

```
    public function find($id);
```

You seems to be looking for the findBy function :

```
public function findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null);
```

Be aware that this function will return a collection and not a single object

Comment: Well no.  $id can actually be an array.  Unusual to do so but it works.  Consider trying to answer the actual question.  Which quite frankly seems a bit incoherent to me.  Good luck.